# How do I make sure that I insert SQL data in right order with Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

When I insert:

```
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
..
..
..
dataN
```

Into a MySQL database with this code:

```
DataLogg dataLogg = new DataLogg(0, time, DO0, DO1, DO2, DO3, AI0, AI1, AI2, AI3, loggerIdValue, samplingTimeValue, pulseNumber, ControlView.selectedBreakPulseLimit, stopSignal, comment);
dataLoggRepository.saveAndFlush(dataLogg);
```

It will insert data like this, if I have bad luck.

```
data1
data2
data4
data3
dataN
..
..
..
data5
```

**Question:**

How can I guarantee that the same order I insert the rows, I can read them as the same order as well? I don't want it in random order. The last data need to be at the top and the first data need to be at the bottom.

Comment: Did you mean order of auto-increment primary key ?

Comment: @Eklavya Yes. I have that implemented. https://github.com/DanielMartensson/OpenSourceLogger/blob/master/src/main/java/se/danielmartensson/views/database/datalogg/DataLogg.java

Comment: If you use saveAll then it will insert the order of given list.

Comment: @Eklavya I did that. But still the database made some random order sometimes. https://github.com/DanielMartensson/OpenSourceLogger/blob/9059ba4d85afae7b930d92d4f7b3b826a70e536a/src/main/java/se/danielmartensson/views/components/threads/SamplingThread.java#L178

Comment: Did you mean auto-increment primary key order is not maintained ? There is no particular order for table it just show by the order of primary key.

Comment: @Eklavya Yes. I have no order for the table, except for the primary key. But can I do ordering on Date and Time in this string format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss:MMMM` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked:

> How can I guarantee that the same order I insert the rows, I can read them as the same order as well?

The answer is that there is no internal "order" to a SQL table, for all intents and purposes.  The way you ensure a certain order when querying is to use an `ORDER BY` clause with the query, e.g.

```
SELECT name
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY name;
```

Comment: I can't do "Order By" in this case. I want to insert them in inserted order.

Comment: Not happening.  There is no formal order in a SQL table, and this has nothing to do with Spring or the framework you are using, it is a database property.

Comment: Can I do order by time?

Comment: I have a time code with this format in a column `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss:MMM`